# JRE7 Unbound error in eclipse - I have 1.8 installed

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

I keep getting this error when I import a project from git. I have tried installing 1.7 but Oracle says I have the most up to date java so i can't install 1.7. If I use the 1.8 JRE then this error goes away but I get errors all over the code. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Eclipse about it. Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs-> Add "Standard VM"

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this by selecting jre7 in the above dialog and clicking remove button on right. And you can set the compliance level of Compiler to 1.7 if you want to use 1.7

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java ->Compiler ->Compiler Compliance Level
```